# Clickfunnels Integration with Coupon Carrier and Aweber

Tags: javascript, forms, coupon, aweber

I wish I was technical. I am working with a programmer but his solution to my issue is expensive. I am just wondering if there is an easier way to fix this or a better solution to what I am trying to accomplish. I am working with an oil change business who has 3 options for oil changes. They want to discount each of the three options and offer them through a clickfunnel (it should operate just like a groupon). The coupon code that is generated after you pick the option you want must be secure and only be able to be used once or else the business will lose money. I am using a service called Coupon Carrier and it seems easy and very secure to deliver redeem button coupon codes.The issue I am having is that when you select a discounted option for an oil change an email is triggered and the code (button) is sent out. The email that is sent with the redeem button says thank you for your purchase but unfortunately I cannot send out three different customized emails for each oil change option. So the same generic message goes out for each one and there is no way to tell which oil change option they picked from the email they received. I need to be able to customize each message so the business cannot be lied to..... Any help would be greatly appreciated...If you think you have a better option for sending out secure redeem button codes through clickfunnels I would be very open to listening about it...

Comment: Pat, I understand that you're trying to receive help. However, there may be a better place to ask these questions. Stack overflow is tailored toward assisting developers with technical issues and not so much design issues or opinions. There is an expectation that you will provide  some code that has an issue and the community will interact with an attempted solution. Check out Stack Exchange to find a better forum for your request.

Comment: I apologize, thank you!